# Android connection encryption

Tags: java, android

I have create application for android which is sending requests to JAVA server (REST - Spring boot), currently the communication is handled via HTTP.

I have created trust store and key store via keytool:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias localhost -keystore keystore.jks -storepass 111111 -validity 360
keytool.exe -export -alias localhost -file localhost.cer -keystore keystore.jks
keytool.exe -import -v -trustcacerts -alias localhost -file localhost.cer -keystore truststore.jks
```

Then I have configured the server:

```
server.ssl.key-alias=FCA
server.ssl.key-password=111111
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

Client is sending requests to server via this code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream instream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);
        keyStore.load(instream, "****".toCharArray());
        instream.close();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("JKS");
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "111111".toCharArray());
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
        client.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("id", newUser.getId());
        jsonObject.addProperty("email", newUser.getEmail());
        jsonObject.addProperty("password", newUser.getPassword());
        jsonObject.addProperty("fname", newUser.getFname());
        jsonObject.addProperty("lname", newUser.getLname());

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(jsonMediaType, new Gson().toJson(jsonObject));

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(ServerValues.SERVER_ADDRESS + "/users")
                .post(requestBody)
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I have tested the server with Post man and it works correctly via HTTPS so the problem is on the client side.
Client is getting the following error:"java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store."
Please help me solve this error.

Comment: Why do all this when you can use HTTPS?

Comment: @zaph Thats what im trying to achieve send requests to server via HTTPS, but in order to do this its needed to create trusts store, key store and certificate isn't it?

Comment: Just get a certificate. Self sign if you control both ends or buy a certificate or even use Let's Encrypt for a certificate. No code needs be written.

Comment: @zeph im using self signed cert, and im controlling both ends, how do I specify (on client side) that I want to use this cert?

Comment: Add the cert to the clients certs store, that is all that is necessary. Of corse the server needs to be setup for HTTPS.